# How to merge outputs of asyncio websockets at the same time?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

### Question

- How can I merge the results of two or three asynchronous websocket results, defined with the library `asyncio`?
- I am downloading order book data (how many people want to buy or sell something at which price) of cryptocurrencies using websockets asynchronously, but having hard time showing the results of several coins.
- The desired output example is as follows, each output (the lowest ask price) of asynchronous webscokets is in a dictionary variable 'output_dict' :

```py
output_dict
>>> {"XRP-BTC" : 0.00023, "ETH-BTC" : 0.04, "LTC-BTC" : 0.001}
```

- Each value is the lowest ask price, provided by a websocket, so what I want to do is to merge the outputs of several asynchronously working webscokets.

### Code Example

```py
import asyncio
import websockets
import ast
import time
import json

# websocket address for the cryptocurrency exchange OKEx
url = "wss://ws.okex.com:8443/ws/v5/public"

# function to download orderbook data, using websocket asynchronously
async def ws_orderbook5(crypto_pair):
    while True:
            try:
                async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
                    channels = [{'channel': 'books5', 'instId': f'{crypto_pair}'}]
                    sub_param = {"op": "subscribe", "args": channels}
                    sub_str = json.dumps(sub_param)
                    await ws.send(sub_str)
                    print(f"send: {sub_str}")
                    res = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=25)

                    while True:
                        try:
                            res = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=25)
                            res = ast.literal_eval(res) 
                            lowest_ask_price = res['data'][0]['asks'][0][0]
                            print(f"{crypto-pair} : Lowest ask price is {lowest_ask_price}")
                            
                            time.sleep(1)

                        except (asyncio.TimeoutError, websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed) as e:
                            try:
                                await ws.send('ping')
                                print("")
                                print("ping")
                                res = await ws.recv()
                                continue
                            except Exception as e:
                                print("Failure due to an unknown error. Stopped working")
                                break
            except Exception as e:
                print("Failure due to an unknown error. Try working again")
                continue
```

- The variable `res`, which is the data downloaded from OKEx websocket looks like the following dictionary, when the argument `crypto_pair` = 'XRP-BTC' .

```py
{'arg': {'channel': 'books5', 'instId': 'XRP-BTC'}, 
 'data': [{'asks': [['0.00002585', '4514.84', '0', '2'], 
                    ['0.00002586', '5845.946', '0', '5'],
                    ['0.00002587', '30306.155', '0', '5'], 
                    ['0.00002588', '9974.105', '0', '7'], 
                    ['0.00002589', '3104.84', '0', '5']], 
           'bids': [['0.00002582', '3988', '0', '2'], 
                    ['0.00002581', '23349.817', '0', '4'], 
                    ['0.0000258', '18735.565', '0', '8'], 
                    ['0.00002579', '6429.196', '0', '6'], 
                    ['0.00002578', '3492.795', '0', '5']], 
           'instId': 'XRP-BTC', 
           'ts': '1622805157064'}]
}
```

- As such what is printed on console is as follows. The argument here, for example, is "XRP-BTC" again.

```py
XRP-BTC : The most favorable ask price is 0.00023
```

- My desired output is a dictionary consisting of name of each pair as a key, and its lowest ask price as a value.

```py
output_dict
>>> {"XRP-BTC" : 0.00023, "ETH-BTC" : 0.04, "LTC-BTC" : 0.001}
```

- Can anyone tell me how I can merge the result of websockets so that I can make the dictionary?

Comment: There's a typo in the code above where there should be an underscore in crypto_pair instead of crypto-pair where >>> 'print(f"{crypto-pair} : Lowest ask price is {lowest_ask_price}")

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your coroutine in a task, one for each currency pair

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(ws_orderbook5(pair1))
loop.create_task(ws_orderbook5(pair2))
loop.create_task(ws_orderbook5(pair3))
loop.run_forever()
```

To merge the results you can add the result of ws.recv() to an `asyncio.Queue` object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you actually provide me with the code explaining how to add the result of ws.recv() to an "asnycio.Queue' object, please?

Comment: Can you also kindly explain me how to extract one key from a dictionary varibles 'res' of each coin pair, and merge them to a single dictionary, as I edited and explained in a question above, please?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html

Comment: The `asyncio.Queue` parameter will be deprecated. It seems to be better to use the `loop` parameter. 
>> Deprecated since version 3.8, will be removed in version 3.10: The loop parameter.